# Cant echo Variable in php

Tags: php, html

When executing the folloing snippet on localhost I get nothing on screen 
enen though I see no mistake in it. How can I print this content on the browser ?

```
<?php

 $outpu = "<table>";
 $outpu. = "<tr><td>";
 $outpu. = "<h6>Admin</h6>";
 $outpu. = "</td>";
 $outpu. = "<td>";
 $outpu. = "<h6>Action</h6>";
 $outpu. = "</td>";
 $outpu. = "</tr>";
 $outpu = "<tr><td>";
 $outpu. = "</td>";
 $outpu. = "<td>";
 $outpu. = "</td>";
 $outpu. = "</tr>";
 $outpu = "</table>";
 echo $outpu;

?>
```

Comment: I see no use in doing echos like that. If you're not using this for anything special, you may as well just use regular HTML and give it a `.php` extension. It will run just as good. Plus, doing concatenates like that is pointless. That isn't coding "style", it's coding "mayhem".

Answer (score 4):

you replace the string at the end of the line

```
 $outpu="</table>";
```

In html it'll be blank

try like this

```
 $outpu.="</table>";
```

also in 11th line

```
$outpu .= "<tr><td>";
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing

Comment: meaning this one `$outpu = "<tr><td>";` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you have a hawk-eye buddy

Comment: hehe, yeah... the way they're echoing like that, is easy to get lost into.

Answer (score 1):

The problem :

```
<?php
$outpu = "<table>";
$outpu. = "<tr><td>";
$outpu. = "<h6>Admin</h6>";
$outpu. = "</td>";
$outpu. = "<td>";
$outpu. = "<h6>Action</h6>";
$outpu. = "</td>";
$outpu. = "</tr>";
$outpu = "<tr><td>"; // Here
$outpu. = "</td>";
$outpu. = "<td>";
$outpu. = "</td>";
$outpu. = "</tr>";
$outpu = "</table>"; // Here
echo $outpu;
?>
```

Try using this code instead above

```
<?php
$outpu = "<table>";
$outpu .= "<tr><td>";
$outpu .= "<h6>Admin</h6>";
$outpu .= "</td>";
$outpu .= "<td>";
$outpu .= "<h6>Action</h6>";
$outpu .= "</td>";
$outpu .= "</tr>";
$outpu .= "<tr><td>";
$outpu .= "</td>";
$outpu .= "<td>";
$outpu .= "</td>";
$outpu .= "</tr>";
$outpu .= "</table>";
echo $outpu;
?>
```

You don't need to make many string concatenation like that, PHP supports multi-lines string :

```
<?php
$outpu = "<table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h6>Admin</h6>
            </td>
            <td>
              <h6>Action</h6>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>";
echo $outpu;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line before the echo statement has `=` instead of the `.=`.
 That's overwriting everything in the var `$outpu`, meaning `$output` = `</table>` which is why you're not getting anything.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better for you to define html codes as per say:

```
<?php
$outpu = <<<EOD
<table>
<tr><td>
<h6>Admin</h6>
</td>
<td><h6>Action</h6></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
EOD;

echo $outpu; ?>
```

It's called [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) syntax.